# Can a bounty be awarded more than once on the same answer?

Tags: support, answers, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Can a bounty be awarded more than once on the same answer to the same question?

Comment: Yes (12 chars to go)

Comment: @JonSeigel: I agree that it is a *close* duplicate, but I recommend that we update that dupe to make it more clear that the same answer can receive more than one bounty, over time...

Comment: Already done. :)

Comment: sweet @JonSeigel, thanks! voted to close.